# Sonar index.txt file is not getting generated SonarQube 5.3

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.3

I can see plugins folders under "sonarqube-5.3\web\deploy\plugins"  but index.txt file is missing and because of it I am getting error while sonar runner execution.

its failing while at following step.

```
GET 404 http://gbrdsm030000221:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution , I deleted everything which were present under web/deploy/plugins folder and restarted sonar server and it has generated index.txt file.